# How can I force Windows to debug an app?

Tags: windows, debugging

Currently I'm trying to debug an application, however, every time it crashes, I see this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

As you can see, there's no <kbd>Debug</kbd> button, so I cannot debug the crash!

It **only** happens with this application; the button appears with every other app that crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like WER (Windows Error Reporting) is handling the crash for this application.  As far as I know, WER handles the crash for all applications that are not .NET or do not have their own crash handler.

In the second screenshot, the 3rd file is a hdmp file.  This is a full dump file generated by WER that you can analyze with windbg.

More information on analyzing user mode dumps in WinDBG is located on this MSDN link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also, if you want to change the defaults for WER, you can alter these reg keys described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx